# CakePHP How to display the data from three related models in one view?

Tags: php, cakephp, view, model

I'm trying to create an application where you can create and answer quizes.
The creation part is already done and I can save Tests, Questions and Answers.

The relations between them:

```
Test $hasMany Question
Question $hasMany Answer
```

I created a viewTest that shows one selected Test and it's related Questions using foreach:

```
echo $test['Test']['id'];  
echo '</br>';



foreach ($test['Question'] as $question){  
    echo $question['text']; 
    echo '<br>';
```

How can I retrieve the Answer data related to each Question?

***EDIT ***

Test Model relation:

```
public $hasMany = array('Question' => array('className' => 'Question', 'foreignKey' => 'idTest'));
```

*Where idTest is the foreignKey on the database*

Question Model relation:

```
public $belongsTo = array('Test' => array('className' => 'Test', 'foreignKey' => 'idTest'));

public $hasMany = array('Answer' => array('className' => 'Answer', 'foreignKey' => 'idQuestion'));
```

Answer Model relation:

```
public $belongsTo = array('Question' => array('className' => 'Question', 'foreignKey' => 'idQuestion'));
```

Test returns:

```
 array (size=2)
  'Teste' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'dataLimite' => string '2014-09-25' (length=10)
      'valorTeste' => string '2' (length=1)
      'numQuestoes' => string '2' (length=1)
  'Questao' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'idTeste' => string '2' (length=1)
          'descricao' => string 'questao1 ' (length=9)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => string '4' (length=1)
          'idTeste' => string '2' (length=1)
          'descricao' => string 'dfsdfa' (length=6)
```

And in the same view for Test, Question returns:

```
    array (size=3)
  'id' => string '3' (length=1)
  'idTeste' => string '2' (length=1)
  'descricao' => string 'questao1 ' (length=9)
```

**EDIT**

On the Question view, Question returns:

```
array (size=3)
  'Questao' => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'idTeste' => string '2' (length=1)
      'descricao' => string 'questao1 ' (length=9)
  'Teste' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'dataLimite' => string '2014-09-25' (length=10)
      'valorTeste' => string '2' (length=1)
      'numQuestoes' => string '2' (length=1)
  'Alternativa' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=5)
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'idQuestao' => string '3' (length=1)
          'isRespostaCerta' => boolean false
          'respostaUsuario' => null
          'descricao' => string 'alternativa 1' (length=13)
      1 => 
        array (size=5)
          'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'idQuestao' => string '3' (length=1)
          'isRespostaCerta' => boolean true
          'respostaUsuario' => null
          'descricao' => string 'alternativa 2' (length=13)
```

Comment: Test $hasMany Question  -- 
Question $hasMany Answer;

The `Question` in both statement is same?
If yes then how about something like : `echo $question['answers']`

Comment: In your Question Model, have u described the relation between Question and Answer ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

On my TestsController I created a viewTests method that gets the data where Test.id = $id(From the index table);

```
 $test = $this->Test->findById($id);
```

Then I write in te Session it's $id and redirrect to QuestionsController

```
    $this->Session->write('idTest',$id);

    return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'questions','action' => 'viewTest'));
```

On the QuestionController I created another viewTests that reads from the Session $idTest info.

```
$idTest = $this->Session->read('idTest');
$this->set('idTest', $idTest);
```

And then I search for the Questions that are related to the Test

```
$this->loadModel('Question');

$questoes = $this->Question->find('all', array(
             'conditions' => array('Question.idTest'=>$idTest)
            ));
$this->set('questions', $questions);
```

My tests_view to retrieve Answers:

```
foreach ($questions as $question){

    foreach ($question['Answer'] as $answer){  



        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you already tried a foreach() at $question['Answer'] ? Try debug($question) and see if it retrieve an array of answers. Sometimes you need a $hasAndBelongsToMany.

Comment: $question in this view doesn't have the Answer information in it; Notice (8): Undefined index and Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach();